# How to darken an image on mouseover and show buttons?

Tags: javascript, css

**My problem...**

I want to darken an image and show buttons on it. When I tried, the buttons got darker too.

I tried this code:

```
<style>
.image {
    background: url('http://carinapilar.com/wp-content/uploads/MinhasHistorias/Capa.Primeiro.Livro.png');
    background-size:contain;
    width: 250px;
    height: 355px;
    position:relative;
}
.image:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

div.show-image:hover input {
    display: block;
}
div.show-image input {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
div.show-image input.update {
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
div.show-image input.delete {
    top:0;
    left:79%;
}

</style>

<div class="show-image">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <input class="update" type="button" value="Update" />
            <input class="delete" type="button" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found only solutions that or bring only the darkened functionality or the buttons on hover... I can't find both together...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s287x3yg/) is the Fiddle.

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xgvvg93g/? which would reduce markup by using a pseudo element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1fmeey0o/) is your solution.

Just move the `input` buttons outside `div.overlay` that you're darkening.

You only need to change your HTML so:

```
<div class="show-image">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
        <input class="update" type="button" value="Update" />
        <input class="delete" type="button" value="Delete" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Unlike @philnash's solution, doesn't need z-index, as the `input` elements are after `div.overlay`.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the buttons out of the overlay and raising them above the overlay with z-index. Check out a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0sr7jc7k/).

Things I changed were moving the buttons:

```
<div class="show-image">
  <div class="image">
    <input class="update" type="button" value="Update" />
    <input class="delete" type="button" value="Delete" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and adding the `z-index` to the inputs:

```
div.show-image input {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of `.overlay` completely and just used `:after`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s287x3yg/6/)

The CSS:

```
.image:after {
    content:'';
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}

.image input {
    z-index:2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="show-image">
    <div class="image">
        <input class="update" type="button" value="Update" />
        <input class="delete" type="button" value="Delete" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to give the button `z-index` so that they would be on top of the fade effect.

Comment: If only you would've used a 'realistic' z-index  :L

Comment: I changed it to be more realistic @jbutler483

Comment: like a single '9' would have been enough :P

Comment: Think I just got excited :P @jbutler483